# How do I resolve "Jupyter notebook Kernel Error"?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, octave, scilab

I am trying to run jupyter notebook on my machine. I went through the steps of installing octave and scilab kernels, as I need these in addition to Python. When I try to create or open a notebook I am not able to execute any code due to a kernel error.

[image: Screenshot of notebook with kernel error]

The error log from the notebook is as follows:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bthlin009\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1704, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "C:\Users\bthlin009\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "c:\users\bthlin009\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 69, in post
    model = yield maybe_future(
  File "C:\Users\bthlin009\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\bthlin009\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "c:\users\bthlin009\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\bthlin009\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\bthlin009\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "c:\users\bthlin009\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 100, in start_kernel_for_session
    kernel_id = yield maybe_future(
  File "C:\Users\bthlin009\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "c:\users\bthlin009\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 176, in start_kernel
    kernel_id = await maybe_future(self.pinned_superclass.start_kernel(self, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\bthlin009\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 185, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bthlin009\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 309, in start_kernel
    kernel_cmd, kw = self.pre_start_kernel(**kw)
  File "C:\Users\bthlin009\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 258, in pre_start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "C:\Users\bthlin009\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 468, in write_connection_file
    self.connection_file, cfg = write_connection_file(self.connection_file,
  File "C:\Users\bthlin009\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 138, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "c:\users\bthlin009\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\bthlin009\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 461, in secure_write
    win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
  File "C:\Users\bthlin009\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 387, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I have tried reinstalling the kernels, and I have added directories of the octave and scilab executable to the system variables. And I have checked that path for the python executable is python38.

What else do I need to do to resolve this?

Comment: Can you show your kernel configuration? Do you have 64bit Python installed?

Comment: Sounds like Tornado doesn't have great support for Windows, so I'd do some research into whether or not your use case has worked for others on Windows

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am using 32 bit Python. The kernel configuration I'm using is this one: https://gist.github.com/IvanMalison/369dbc15a05a41d3ab6616e12d591a94

Comment: That's a Jupyter config. Not a kernel. I think the command is something like `jupyter kernelspec` to find where those are... But anyways, your scilab executables / kernel (not Tornado) is trying to run a non-Windows binary, so you need to show us how you installed that

Comment: I have no tried to reinstall Python and also removed previous Python versions, Now the kernels seem to be loading successfully and there are no more error messages on the notebook but I still can't get the code in the cells to run. On commdand propmt I'm seeing a "`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'juptyter_linter'`' message.

Comment: After installing jupyter-linter using pip. I got Python and Octave working. Will try to troubleshoot scilab